# Sklearn: How to adjust data set proportion during training, but not testing

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, cross-validation

I'm using sklearn/pandas/numpy.

I have a labeled data set, where the potential outcomes are either True or False. However, the data set has a much higher proportion of True entries. When running through classifiers with k-fold (n=5) cross validation, this appears to bias the classifier towards just saying True.

Using weights, I was able to adjust the sample data set I'm using to have a proportion closer to 1:1, like so (using a pandas csv):

```
results = csv[['result']]
weights = np.where(results.as_matrix() == True,0.25,1).ravel()
csv_sample = csv.sample(n=60000, weights=weights)
```

And the results are much more promising! However, I'm wondering if there's a way for me to do cross validation where the TRAINING set is adjusted in this manner, but the TEST set is closer to the actual proportion of data.

Comment: Have you tried sample_weight=balanced or auto in your model? This takes care of unbalanced datasets rather nicely.

Comment: @Diego I'm pretty new to sklearn, so I did not know about this feature! Will definitely look into it, cause it seems promising, thank you

Comment: Yes, go ahead then. It was a blessing for what I was trying to do. I have added this as an answer so in case this works for you don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use predictor option class_weight='balanced' or auto. It worked really well for me for [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) in a similar situation.

Comment: To clarify, the class_weight value is dependent on the docs for the classifier, the one I was looking at only had "balanced" and "balanced_subsample", and when digging through the code, I noticed that, at least in this particular instance, 'auto' was being deprecated just through I'd note for anyone else passing this question/answer!

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the "auto" just in case an older version of sklearn has to be used.